# Recursion and Big O

Tags: recursion, computer-science, complexity-theory, big-o

I've been working through a recent Computer Science homework involving recursion and big-O notation. I believe I understand this pretty well (certainly not perfectly, though!) But there is one question in particular that is giving me the most problems. The odd thing is that by looking it, it looks to be the most simple one on the homework.

Provide the best rate of growth using the big-Oh notation for the solution to the following recurrence?

T(1) = 2

T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + 1 for n>1

And the choices are:

- O(n log n)
- O(n^2)
- O(2^n)
- O(n^n)

I understand that big O works as an upper bound, to describe the most amount of calculations, or the highest running time, that program or process will take. I feel like this particular recursion should be O(n), since, at most, the recursion only occurs once for each value of n. Since n isn't available, it's either better than that, O(nlogn), or worse, being the other three options.

So, my question is: Why isn't this O(n)?

Comment: I kept reading that as "T(1) = (2 T(n))", but I think you meant "T(1) = 2, and T(n) = [...]".  Correct?

Comment: Can you put each clause on a newline?

Comment: Yeah, because as I read it right now, the results go: 2, 5, 11, 23, etc...

Comment: Can I downvote the professor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to solve recurrences: substitution, recurrence tree and master theorem.  Master theorem won't work in the case, because it doesn't fit the master theorem form.

You could use the other two methods, but the easiest way for this problem is to solve it iteratively.

T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1
T(n) = 4T(n-2) + 2 + 1
T(n) = 8T(n-3) + 4 + 2 + 1
T(n) = ...

See the pattern?

T(n) = 2<sup>n-1</sup>⋅T(1) + 2<sup>n-2</sup> + 2<sup>n-3</sup> + ... + 1
T(n) = 2<sup>n-1</sup>⋅2 + 2<sup>n-2</sup> + 2<sup>n-3</sup> + ... + 1
T(n) = 2<sup>n</sup> + 2<sup>n-2</sup> + 2<sup>n-3</sup> + ... + 1

Therefore, the tightest bound is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped. I had noticed that the pattern was 2*last + 1, but instead of doing it iteratively with powers, I was trying an odd type of for loop. I see now why it is exponential.

Comment: Big is computational complexity not the bound.You are calling T() n times. You could easily rewrite this as a simple loop.

Comment: T(n) = 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + 2^(n-3) + ... + 1: That would be exactly 2^n - 1, and would be wrong.

Comment: Of course yes. But the solution to the recursion is not T(n) = 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + 2^(n-3) + ... + 1 = 2^n - 1. It is instead T(n) = 2^(n-1) + 2^n - 1 = 3*2^(n-1) - 1.

Comment: Good point.  I jumped the gun and thought T(1)=1.  I corrected the post.

Comment: I am surprised that this is the accepted answer.  What is written is incomplete: it does not yet show that $T(n)$ is at most a constant times $2^n$.  For this you need to sum the finite geometric series and get the answer suggested by Federico Ramponi in the comment above.  (And why doesn't his correct answer have any upvotes as yet?)

Answer (score 15):

I think you have misunderstood the question a bit.  It does not ask you how long it would take to solve the recurrence. It is asking what the big-O (the asymptotic bound) of the solution itself is.

What you have to do is to come up with a closed form solution, i. e. the non-recursive formula for T(n), and then determine what the big-O of that expression is.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be exponential. Each increment to n makes the value to be twice as large.

```
T(2) = 2 * T(1) = 4
T(3) = 2 * T(2) = 2 * 4
...
```

T(x) would be the running time of the following program (for example):

```
def fn(x):
 if (x == 1):
  return    # a constant time
 # do the calculation for n - 1 twice
 fn(x - 1)
 fn(x - 1)
```

Comment: In that case, it would be O(n log n) because the time required to multiply the result is O(log n).

Comment: Correct - they don't want you to measure the run time of the expression, they want to measure the output of the expression.

Comment: I do have the output of the expression in mind (i.e. if you plot the function T, it will be an exponential plot).

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking for the big-Oh notation for the solution to the recurrence, not the cost of calculation the recurrence.

Put another way: the recurrence produces:

```
  1 -> 2
  2 -> 5
  3 -> 11
  4 -> 23
  5 -> 47
```

What big-Oh notation best describes the sequence 2, 5, 11, 23, 47, ...

The correct way to solve that is to solve the recurrence equations.

Answer (score 1):

> I think this will be exponential. Each increment to n brings twice as much calculation.

No, it doesn't. Quite on the contrary:

Consider that for *n* iterations, we get running time *R*. Then for *n* + 1 iterations we'll get exactly *R* + 1.

Thus, the growth rate is constant and the overall runtime is indeed *O*(*n*).

However, I think Dima's assumption about the question is right although his solution is overly complicated:

> What you have to do is to come up with a closed form solution, i. e. the non-recursive formula for T(n), and then determine what the big-O of that expression is.

It's sufficient to examine the relative size of *T*(*n*) and *T*(*n* + 1) iterations and determine the relative growth rate. The amount obviously doubles which directly gives the asymptotic growth.

Answer (score 1):

First off, all four answers are worse than O(n)... O(n*log n) is more complex than plain old O(n). What's bigger: 8 or 8 * 3, 16 or 16 * 4, etc...

On to the actual question. The general solution can obviously be solved in constant time if you're not doing recursion

( T(n) = 2^(n - 1) + 2^(n) - 1 ), so that's not what they're asking.

And as you can see, if we write the recursive code:

```
int T( int N )
{
    if (N == 1) return 2;
    return( 2*T(N-1) + 1);
}
```

It's obviously O(n).

So, it appears to be a badly worded question, and they are probably asking you the growth of the function itself, not the complexity of the code. That's 2^n. Now go do the rest of your homework... and study up on O(n * log n)

Answer (score 1):

Computing a closed form solution to the recursion is easy.
By inspection, you guess that the solution is

```
T(n) = 3*2^(n-1) - 1
```

Then you prove by induction that this is indeed a solution. Base case:

```
T(1) = 3*2^0 - 1 = 3 - 1 = 2. OK.
```

Induction:

```
Suppose T(n) = 3*2^(n-1) - 1. Then
T(n+1) = 2*T(n) + 1 = 3*2^n - 2 + 1 = 3*2^((n+1)-1) - 1. OK.
```

where the first equality stems from the recurrence definition,
and the second from the inductive hypothesis. QED.

3*2^(n-1) - 1 is clearly Theta(2^n), hence the right answer is the third.

To the folks that answered O(n): I couldn't agree more with Dima. The problem does **not** ask the tightest upper bound to the computational complexity of an algorithm to compute T(n) (which would be now O(1), since its closed form has been provided). The problem asks for the tightest upper bound *on T(n) itself*, and that is the exponential one.